# How to download a whole soundcloud channel and/or playlist (all tracks from a channel would be better) with youtube-dl?

Tags: soundcloud, youtube-dl

I'm well used to youtube-dl to do many things, but I never tried to download a whole soundcloud channel, at the best quality possible all at once. I can do it locally on ubuntu mate 20.04, but since self-update is not allowed on debian for some reason, I can also do it on my server through ssh, where my programs/apps are all well updated, if not by me, by the service providers themselves.

Grateful.

Answer (score -1):

Soooo I basically go to the tracks tab, playlist, albums, liked, and copy all the links in a stack and copy and then just hit the yt -a and it grabs the clipboard then I folder all that music into one leaving the downloaded.txt in place and keep it moving. 9k in a week using this method 1 machine.

Now after create 7 layer network I get SSL cert issues LOL! back to linux.......

https://github.com/ddelange/yt
now I use yt-dlp tho